# In Unity/C#, how those different inputs work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a game in a Unity/C# course, and there is a coop mode.

PlayerOne and PlayerTwo have two different inputs methods and they behave differently. PlayerOne seems to have a small delay between the time I press the button and the time it moves in-game. Or maybe it just needs to accelerate, while PlayerTwo just reaches the speed instantly.

```
void CalculateMovement()
{
     if (_PlayerTwo == false)
     {
         float HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         float VerticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
         Vector3 direction = new Vector3(HorizontalInput, VerticalInput, 0);

         if (_speedBoostActive == false)
         {
             transform.Translate(direction * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         else
         {
             transform.Translate(direction * (_speed * 1.5f) * Time.deltaTime);
         }
    }
    // The code above is for PlayerOne    
    else
    {
         float _speedboost = 1.0f;

         if (_speedBoostActive == true)
         {
             _speedboost = 1.5f;
         }

         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad8))
         {
             transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _speed * _speedboost * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad5))
         {
             transform.Translate(Vector3.down * _speed * _speedboost * Time.deltaTime);
         }

         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad4))
         {
             transform.Translate(Vector3.left * _speed * _speedboost * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad6))
         {
             transform.Translate(Vector3.right * _speed * _speedboost * Time.deltaTime);
         }
     }

     // The code above is for PlayerTwo. Below are just a way to delimit an area in the game and create a wrap in x-axis

     transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, -3.9f, 0), 0);

     if (transform.position.x > 9.6f)
     {
         transform.position = new Vector3(-9.6f, transform.position.y, 0);
     }
     else if (transform.position.x < -9.6f)
     {
         transform.position = new Vector3(9.6f, transform.position.y, 0);
     }
}
```

Anyone knows why there's is a difference? I just created based on what the course said to do, but there is no explanation for this difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be caused by a couple of issues which you may want to address

firstly make sure the fiction and mass that you have set in the rigid body are the same between the two players

if that is not the issue it could be a problem with the time.deltatime you have in the code I recommend using the time.fixeddeltatime instead because it makes the player move at a consistent rate rather than delta time which will vary between frames

another reason could be because of any physics material you have set to the player 1 game object but not set to the player 2 game object causing the player 1 object to move with a delay but not the player 2 gameobject

if the problem is with the program then you could also use a program like the one below for your horizontal movement which could be more consistent

```
public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(50, 50);
float inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(speed.x * inputX, 0, 0);
movement *= Time.fixeddeltaTime;
transform.Translate(movement);
```

Through using this code on platformers before it works well for me but may not be the best for your project

I hope this helps you solve your issue